# Modularity in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

### Background

When I look for modularity in TypeScript, I often get the answers around AMD or CommonJS.

What I was looking for is a method to impose clear boundaries between groups of TS files.

Let's call that a logical group of TS files a module. Within a module, each file can import any other files. However, if an import is from module A to module B, it should be forbidden by an ESLint Rule or something like that.

The closest thing I can find is `namespace`, and its bizarre syntax like `/// <reference path="XXX.ts" />`. Although it DID provide a solution for my need for encapsulation on a group of files, this seems to add too much overhead.

I was looking a lightweight alternative to `namespace`. Can be a third-party library, or any creative ESLint Rule.

### My Attempt

I gave a bit more thoughts to it. I managed to come up with an approach:

We can introduce a folder called `__internal__`. If we import from a path that has `__internal__`, we identify the last `__internal__` segment, if there are more than one. And find the prefix of that segment.

For example, for `a/b/c/__internal__/x/y/z`, the prefix of the last `__internal__` is `a/b/c`.

Then we check if the current path shares the same prefix. In the example, the path has to be `a/b/c/*`. The import is considered valid if and only if they have the same prefix.

### Questions

**Question 1:** Do you think this approach makes sense? What are the issues with this?

**Question 2:** Do we have something like this already? I suspect that this should be a common need.

**Question 3:** What other industry-standard alternatives do we have?

Comment: "Let's call that a logical group of TS files a module. Within a module, each file can import any other files." Yes, that's how [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) work. This functionality exists, so no need to roll your own.

Comment: But there’s nothing preventing me from importing A from a different part of the code base B. Even A and B are not in the same module!